# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 end of life support

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Does anyone know when the 'end of life support' runs out for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0?

And, what exactly does that mean?

We're replacing an in-house system and there is serious internal panic that the project isn't moving fast enough, so I'm curious what happens when support is 'switched off' and we are still using it.

Thanks very much

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/06/20/support-ending-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0/

Comment: You would no longer receive security updates.  That is the biggest impact of End of Life.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 Extended support ends [10th April 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20Dynamics%20CRM%204.0). What that means is described in further detail [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14085/microsoft-business-developer-and-desktop-operating-systems-policy).

You lose access to the following. *Note; access to some of these has already been limited or removed.*

- Request to change product design and features.
- Security updates.
- Nonsecurity updates.
- Complimentary support.
- Paid support.

It's probably worth checking your licences to see if/when they are going to expire, but generally CRM 4 should remain functional post-April 2018. However, Microsoft probably won't be; providing updates, or help to resolve issues you encounter.